# mysql group by with unformatted dates and auto sum

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a house price search for my site and I have the land registry data for previous house sales over the last 15 years.

I am trying to do a mysql query to search a postcode for previous house sales and then group them by year so I am looking for a result like this:

```
2043    avg price was £158,000
2013    avg price was £135,000
2012    avg price was £128,000
and so on.
```

My data is stored in my database like this :

```
Date                    Street                   PostCode     Price

2014-03-24 00:00        24 HATHERLEY AVENUE      L23 0SD      192500
2013-03-24 00:00        12 staley road           L23 0SR      185000
2014-03-24 00:00        1  miitchell road        L23 0SD      212000
2013-03-24 00:00        2  black grove           L23 2PL      95000
2014-03-24 00:00        73 mark road             L23 4PL      275000
```

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM PricePaid ,
WHERE postCode = '$loc' 
ORDER BY Date DESC ");
```

I am currently returning the results and calculating all the averages with php. I know there is a way I can do this just in mysql as this database has millions of rows and I am looking for a stream line way of doing this.

My mysql is not that good can someway explain to me how I can group the year and then count each property by year and also ass up the prices as well to get total properties sold and total price for the yeay so I can then calculate the averages.

Much appreciated

Comment: The answes is in the question: _how can I group the year_ -- use `GROUP BY year`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS year, AVG(Price) AS avg_price
FROM PricePaid
WHERE postCode = '$loc'
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT YEAR(Date),avg(Price) FROM PricePaid WHERE postCode=? GROUP BY 1 ORER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: WOW, I was expecting long winded solutions. That is exactly what I was looking for I understand it and have just tried it and it works perfectly for me. Out of interest could you explain what the group by 1 order 1 is doing ?

Comment: If you mean the `1`, it's just that instead of specifying column names or expressions, you can specify which of the (output) columns you use, so `1` just refers to `YEAR(Date)`. If you mean the `GROUP BY`, well, it does just that, group lines that have the same value for the given column(s). You can then use aggregate functions (e.g. `count`, `sum`, `avg`, `min`, `max`...) on other columns.

Comment: Thanks again jcaron you are good at what you do, much appreciated have a good evening